# I was trying to insert websocket API's in a project that uses REST API's using scala.When I compile the program this error occurs

Tags: scala, websocket

I'm trying to establish a websocket connection. I'm trying this in a already created project. And this error occurs.

> Type mismatch, expected: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any], actual:
>   server.Route

The error occurs at route

```
val binding = Http().bindAndHandle(route, interface, port)
  println(s"Server is now online at http://$interface:$port\nPress RETURN 
to stop...")
  StdIn.readLine()

  binding.flatMap(_.unbind()).onComplete(_ => actorSystem.terminate())
  println("Server is down...")

val route=path("ws-echo") {
(get) {
  val requestHandler: HttpRequest ⇒ HttpResponse = {
    case req@HttpRequest( GET, Uri.Path( "/greeter" ), _, _, _ ) ⇒
     req.header[UpgradeToWebSocket] match {
      case Some( upgrade ) ⇒ upgrade.handleMessages( 
         greeterWebSocketService 
    )
  case None ⇒ HttpResponse( 400, entity = "Not a valid websocket 
  request!" )
 }
case r: HttpRequest =>
  r.discardEntityBytes() 
  HttpResponse( 404, entity = "Unknown resource!" )
  }
 }
}




override implicit val system = ActorSystem()
override implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
override implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
override val logger = Logging(system, getClass)

implicit val mat: Materializer
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("akka-system")

val router: server.Route = routes
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
val interface = config.getString("app.interface")
val port = config.getInt("app.port")

Http().bindAndHandle(router, Configuration.httpInterface, 
Configuration.httpPort)
```

Comment: What is the definition of `route`? If the error is in `bindAndHandle` then the rest of this code is not relevant.

Comment: The error is displayed in the route. And it shows -- Type mismatch, expected: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any], actual: server.Route.

Comment: By the way is it correct to try to establish a websocket API in a already created project that has REST API's??

Comment: It is possible to add a websocket endpoint to an existing Akka Http server, but we can't help find the error unless you show us your code! Where is the websocket code? How are you creating `route`?

Comment: Can you tell me that is it possible to get a server.Route in websocket API that has Unit as output??

Comment: You can update the question with this code

Comment: I took out all the API's and ran only the webSocket API. Then this error occured.
 [error] found : Unit 
 [error] required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route 
 [error] (which expands to) akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]  @Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're getting this error on the line `val binding = Http().bindAndHandle(route, interface, port)`, is that correct?

Indeed [`bindAndHandle` expects a `Flow`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/HttpExt.html#bindAndHandle(handler:akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest,akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse,Any],interface:String,port:Int,connectionContext:akka.http.scaladsl.ConnectionContext,settings:akka.http.scaladsl.settings.ServerSettings,log:akka.event.LoggingAdapter)(implicitfm:akka.stream.Materializer):scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.Http.ServerBinding]):

```scala
def bindAndHandle(
  handler: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any],
  interface: String,
  port: Int = DefaultPortForProtocol,
  connectionContext: ConnectionContext = defaultServerHttpContext,
  settings: ServerSettings = ServerSettings(system),
  log: LoggingAdapter = system.log)(implicit fm: Materializer
): Future[ServerBinding]
```

So why do so many examples show passing in a `Route`? The 'magic' here that there's an implicit conversion available to turn a `Route` into a `Flow`.

This is basically an implementation detail, you normally shouldn't have to care about this, but the implicit conversion is [route2HandlerFlow](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/server/RouteResult$.html#route2HandlerFlow(route:akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route)(implicitroutingSettings:akka.http.scaladsl.settings.RoutingSettings,implicitparserSettings:akka.http.scaladsl.settings.ParserSettings,implicitmaterializer:akka.stream.Materializer,implicitroutingLog:akka.http.scaladsl.server.RoutingLog,implicitexecutionContext:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext,implicitrejectionHandler:akka.http.scaladsl.server.RejectionHandler,implicitexceptionHandler:akka.http.scaladsl.server.ExceptionHandler):akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest,akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse,akka.NotUsed]):

```scala
 implicit def route2HandlerFlow(
   route: Route
 )(
   implicit routingSettings: RoutingSettings,
   parserSettings: ParserSettings,
   materializer: Materializer,
   routingLog: RoutingLog,
   executionContext: ExecutionContext = null,
   rejectionHandler: RejectionHandler = RejectionHandler.default,
   exceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler = null
 ): Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed]
```

As you can see, this implicit conversion requires some other implicit values to be available. I suspect you are missing one of those. I *think* it might be enough to introduce an implicit `Materializer`, could you give that a try?

Comment: Thanks for answering man, but it didn't work. But if possible, can you tell me what's the best way to establish a websocket connection having scala in backend using Advanced REST client?? I'm using websockets trying to produce a response whenever there is a change in value in the database.

Comment: What did not work? Can you share (ideally runnable) sample code where you do have an `implicit val mat: Materializer` in scope and still get the error from this question?

Comment: If I have an implicit val mat: Materializer in scope, then this error occurs.  Type mismatch, expected: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any], actual: server.Route . What should I do? Can you guide me through this??

Comment: From the example it seems you now have 2 implicit materializers - does it help when you make sure you have exactly one?

Comment: Actually the error is persistent. Can you tell me how to convert Route to Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any]?? I'm rather new to websocket concepts. Are there anything new to be done to establish a websocket connection?

Comment: You could explicitly `val flow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any] = RouteResult.route2HandlerFlow(route)`. This should at least give you a more specific error message.

Comment: If I implement all the implicit values for the above answer, it shows "Only classes can have declared but undefined members" kind of error  and in the object it shows "Object creation impossible, since member materializer: Materializer in com.alumini.CollegeAlumniRegistrationService is not defined" kind of error

Comment: Sounds like instead of just `implicit val mat: Materializer` you'd want something like `implicit val mat: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()` (and put it after the `ActorContext` initialization)

Comment: Do you think that the above code at "val route" is enough to establish a websocket connection using Advanced REST Client??@Arnout Engelen

Comment: Yes, it's like the example at https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/websocket-support.html#example so that looks OK.